# Flutter Open Youtube or Instagram Using Webview

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview

As the title said, how to open youtube, instagram or facebook inside flutter webview? Or is it even possible to do that at all?

And also is there any limitation or restriction for webview in Flutter? Like which website can be or can't be opened inside webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any website can be opened in a flutter webview. To use webview in your app use webview_flutter plugin, and visit the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) of the plugin for the configuration.

After everything is setup up, use the below Widget with the website url.

```
WebView(
initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Web view Widget in flutter

```
WebView(
    initialUrl: 'https://flutter.io',
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  ),
```

use Instagram or YouTube URL in initialUrl property
follow this link for more detail
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-webview#2